# Is "I never heard that before. It's pretty corny." an oxymoron or what?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Today  I was watching a movie -  *Hacksaw Ridge* in which the lead actor flirts with the actress.

The conversation was like this:

He: *Ever since you stuck me with that needle, my heart's been beating real fast. Every time I think about you it beats faster still.*

Then the actress replies - *I never heard that before. It's pretty corny.*

The dictionary meaning of word *corny* is  something which is trite, banal, common. The actress first said that she had never heard that before means that was something new for her but then why did she call it *corny*? Aren't  both sentences opposite of each other?

Comment: Check [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/corny)

Comment: @VarunNair  Checked but the question still remains same.

Comment: Somethings may sound corny, just by the way it is said by the speaker. Although you may have not heard it before, but somethings sound very cheesy if it is said in a particular tone. Maybe she meant that?

Comment: Where did you find a dictionary that says it means "common"?  I can't find any dictionary that says that.  The definitions are usually more like "so simple, sentimental, or old-fashioned as to be annoying" or "trite, banal, or mawkishly sentimental", which fit perfectly.

Comment: She could be speaking sarcastically when she says that she's never heard that before. How original of you (not). Or that it's so corny that none of the guys who have hit on her before have used the line, and she's heard some fairly corny lines.  Which it is would depend on how she intoned "never" and "pretty", or "that".

Comment: @stangdon You can visit the link of Cambridge dictionary shared in first comment.

Comment: This 1937 text glosses "corny jokes" as "vaudeville for stale": 
 https://books.google.com/books?id=SjMXAQAAMAAJ&q=%22corny+jokes%22&dq=%22corny+jokes%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi97rqc5_fWAhWhy4MKHb1lDXoQ6AEIdTAT

Answer (score 1):

Something "corny" to me is something that is cheesy, silly, cliché or overused, normally in a (overly) sentimental way.

Of course, you don't have to have heard the exact phrase before to think that it *or its style* is any of the above.

A lot of chat-up lines in a bar might be considered "corny" too. "Your eyes sparkle like diamonds" might not win you a date for the night, even if it hasn't been heard before; it's corny!

Answer (score 0):

(a) I've never understood "corny" to mean "common". It means sentimental or melodramatic, in a way that is or borders on silly. It doesn't mean "common" in the sense of a a cliche.

(b) In any case, "I never heard that before" could well be sarcastic. Saying "you make my heart beat faster" to a nurse is probably the sort of line she's heard a million times.